# how to use ar.js studio for pixel 4XL phone

Tags: ar.js

I used ar.js studio to create this:

https://ar.3dtwins.de

it should react to the default marker:

https://github.com/AR-js-org/studio/blob/master/assets/default-marker.png

but for some reason, it's not working.
(It works on with my notebook browser/camera but not with my pixel 4xl)

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please explain what exactly is not working for you? I Used my pixel 3 and it seems to have worked fine. It may take a while to load if you have a heavy 3D model. Make sure you give camera permission to the browser and that your browser version is up to date.

Comment: thanks for looking into it - im using the pixel 4xml wit default Chrome browser. I tried with different models (smallest was about 6MB) and I also tried with just PNG - I just don't see anything

Comment: one more thing. I compared with with the iphone X (where it works) the picture in the camera preview of the pixel 4XL looks much larger than in the iPhone X. Could that be an issue ?

Comment: It could definitely be the problem. Try using a scale of 0.1 and see if it helps (compare with your iPhone to make sure it really had scaled the model)

Comment: sorry - where exactly do i apply the scale ?

Comment: In your html object entity, you can add scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" right after your src